# Dismiss text is not displayed.android case view

Tags: java, android, showcaseview

I am using case view in my app.
But because I use long text, Dismiss text is not displayed.

Because I used it on a large edit-text, the radius of the circle inside it increased and not all the text could fit inside.

```
  ShowcaseConfig config =new ShowcaseConfig();
        config.setDelay(500);
        MaterialShowcaseSequence sequence =new MaterialShowcaseSequence(AddSupportActivity.this, SHOWCASE_ID);

        sequence.setConfig(config);

        sequence.addSequenceItem(mEdtDevName,
                "You can enter the identifier of each supporter here There is nothing wrong with not filling in this field", "GOT IT");

        sequence.addSequenceItem(mEdtProName,
                "Each supporter can have a number of projects in a specific time period.Note: A project has only one supporter at a given time period", "GOT IT");

        sequence.start();
```

Update:
this issue will solve by adding this line:

```
config.shapePadding = 50
```

Comment: And your question is what, how to display this text? and is the text shown only partially or not at all? Did you follow [this](https://github.com/deano2390/MaterialShowcaseView/blob/master/README.md) example?

Comment: @Ruli yes.and I edit my post. Sometimes dismiss text won't open. Or sometime it show text  on bottom

Comment: yes it is clear now, I unfortunately do not know the reason

Comment: @Ruli Is there any way to change textsize?